# Extended Ubuntu partition taking more than it should

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, windows-7

Consider the following picture,

[image]

As I understand from my research, partition 0 is an extended partition which doesn't exist physically, but it's only a partition that includes more logical partitions which is partition 3 and 4 (and partition 4 is the logical one that contains my Ubuntu installation)
Am I right so far?

So now I'm stuck with this logical partition and can't delete it, because it's a part of an extended partition and I need to keep it that way, right?

Is Ubuntu going to use this partition "3" if it runs out of space on its partition "4"?
Also, why did Ubuntu create this partition (I mean the extended one!)

What can and can't I do?

Comment: i've rewritten the whole topic in a better and easier way, please have a look now and lemme know, thanks in advance

Comment: well it's kali, installed by burning iso to usb and booting the usb
on the setup i remember formatting the 29GB driver as ext4 but i did not create a swap partition (it warned me about that) and yes it's not NTFS and yes the windows can't even read it as a partition or even know it's used/free size, and i will get you a screenshot from Gparted
but after this info i still can't figure out if it created this extended virtual partition and included another partition to use it as swap partition while it still has it's own partition ?
if no enough info ill login and get you the screenshot

Comment: im sorry but i was not even sure if what im saying is entirely true so here is the question
i can't delete that 41GB because i can't delete the extended virtual partition that kali created, so call will use this 41 as swap but i still can use it on both windows and kali with no problem, also i should not make it full so it find enough space to use it as swap, is that correct ? please post as an answer so i accept it so you get rep. for helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you came to this situation.

You have 2 primary partitions and 1 extended partition. These are partition 1, 2 and 0 respectively.

Inside the extended partition 0 (70GB) you have 2 logical partitions. Partition 3 (`NTSF` D: 41GB) and Partition 4 (`ext4` mounted as `/` for Ubuntu 29GB).

You cannot delete the extended partition without deleting the two logical partitions inside it. If you delete partition 4, your Ubuntu will be gone too.

You don't have a Swap partition. Creating a 41 GB Swap partition is probably a huge waste of your disk space.

You can continue to use the D: (partition 3) as a shared space between Windows and Ubuntu.

You can delete the logical partition 3 and expand the Ubuntu logical partition to fill the whole extended partition. This can't be done from Windows, as Windows doesn't understand `ext4` partitions. This can't be done from Ubuntu booted from partition 4. You can't change it while the system is running from it.

You have to boot from a Live USB (Use the Try Ubuntu option). Run Gparted from the Live USB and

1. Delete the 41GB partition.
2. Move the 29GB `/` partition to the left edge of the extended
   partition.
3. Expand the `/` partition to the right to fill up all the space in the logical partition.
4. Optionally create a Swap partition of 4GB at the end of the logical
   partition.
5. Boot from Ubuntu and enable the swap partition.

Hope this helps